# Null Conditional Operator should used until what? ?.ToString()?.Trim() etc

Tags: c#, .net, operators, null-conditional-operator

I have misunderstanding some of Null-conditional operator ?. mechanism

Example getting Length of String variable

```
object variable = null;
int? Length = variable?.ToString()?.Trim()?.Length;
```

Should we using `?.` operator in all cascading properties of members of object we need test ?
The variable object is null so testing with null-conditional operator should be for `ToString()` method only or cascading members of `ToString()` ?

This

```
?.ToString()?.Trim()?.Length
```

OR

```
?.ToString().Trim().Length
```

I though that if `ToString` is null there's no need for test next member after it.

Comment: `int? Length =...`, please note `?` or `int Length = ... ?? 0;`

Comment: a) You can test this for yourself. b) You only need the `variable?` one (assuming that `ToString` never returns `null`, which is a pretty safe bet).

Comment: That depends on the members you´re calling. Can the ever be null? E.g. `Trim` does **never** return `null`, `ToString` however **can**.

Comment: Its not for ToString(). this is for example, but maybe you have Image or anything that you need many nesting members from it.

Comment: If the method can't return `null` then you don't need `?` after it. The rule really is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, null conditional operator returns either `null` or some `class`; since `int` is a `struct` you can't put

```
// Doesn't compile. What is Length when variable == null?
int Length = variable?.ToString()?.Trim()?.Length;
```

but either use `Nullable<int>`

```
// Now Length can be null if variable is null
int? Length = variable?.ToString()?.Trim()?.Length;
```

or turn `null` into reasonable `int`:

```
// in case variable is null let Length be -1
int Length = variable?.ToString()?.Trim()?.Length ?? -1;
```

Since `null.ToString()` throws exception then `?.` in `variable?.ToString()` is *mandatory*; all the other `?.` are *optional* if we assume that `ToString()` and `Trim()` never return `null`.

1. if `variable` is `null` then `?.` will immediately returns `null`
2. if `variable` is not `null`, both `.ToString()` and `.Trim()` will not return `null` and the check `?.` is redundant.

So you can put either

```
int? Length = variable?.ToString().Trim().Length;
```

Or

```
int Length = variable?.ToString().Trim().Length ?? -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The null-conditional operator is just syntactic sugar for a null-check. So the following two codes are similar:

```
object variable = null;
int? Length = variable?.ToString()?.Trim()?.Length;
```

VS:

```
object variable = null;
int? Length;
if(variable != null)
{
    var a = variable.ToString()?;
    if(a != null)
    {
        var result = a.Trim();
        if(result != null)
            Length = result.Length;
    }
}
```

So depending on if the member can even return `null`- e.g. `ToString`may while `Trim` does not - you may have to check for it using `?`.

In your example you can omit the check for `Trim`, but not for `ToString`.